# Is my understanding of abstraction, encapsulation and their relationship correct?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation, abstraction

Now I know there is a sea of articles and questions dealing with this and having gone through most of it, I need to know if my understanding is accurate.

**Abstraction** : A way to deal with complexities. We basically identify the bare minimum essentials while omitting the non essential details. A simplification.

**Encapsulation** :  The process of wrapping things up into one single black box. The black box offers different services but everything is tied down as one single unit.

**The relationship** : Abstraction gives us a clear distinction between the interface (the essentials) and the implementation (the non essentials). Now when these ideas are being implemented, the non essentials goes inside the black box, while the interface provides us with the services. In other words, the implementation of the abstracted concepts is encapsulation.

**In programming terms:** Interfaces and abstract classes are used to define the abstracted out concepts. A concrete class that extends or implements these, is our black box (encapsulation). Accessors, mutators and modifiers are used to improve the black box. So basically, how good our encapsulation is depends on how good our abstraction is.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're understanding of the concepts seems clear good to me. The only thing that I'd add is that encapsulation is not "per se" necessarily related with abstraction. 
In OOP, encapsulation refers to the internal state of the objects, even if they don't extend an abstract superclass or implement an interface.

Breaking down the concept in concrete terms, I'd say it's the process of hiding the implementation of some services offered outside (that thus can be modified or changed later without needing to change anything outside the encapsulated object) while offering the same "view", the same usable interface (the exposed methods of the object) to the other objects/users that interact with it.

That said, you could say encapsulation is a requirement of abstraction: if you don't "encapsulate" what you want to abstract, it means you're offering a concrete implementation that remains the same for all the objects that extend/implement it, thus losing any abstraction.